# Upload multiple files while navigating other pages - howto?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, asynchronous

I'm creating a website and I'd like to allow users to upload multiple files **while they navigate the website**.

When the upload completes, it would be nice to have a Javascipt event triggered, to allow the user to specify additional info related to the uploaded files (eg. photo location, tags, etc)
anyway, the required features are:

1. multiple files allowed for a single upload operation
2. display an optional progress indicator (at least in the "x of y files uploaded" fashion)
3. doing it without tying the users to a single page

How can I implement these features?
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

---

**Edit**

In the event of using a popup window to handle uploads, how can I:

1. inform the user (on the "master" page) that the upload has completed, or that there have been errors?
2. (more important) pass the $_FILES array to the popup window? I'd like the user to be able to click "upload" on the main window, or anyway to make the upload start from the main window (eg dragging and dropping files on the main window).

Comment: I think the user has to stay on the page to complete the upload, if the user navigates to a different page the upload will stop... one way would be to use frames where a hidden frame will upload the files and the other frame will be used for navigating..

Comment: @qxxx in that case, can the URL in the URL bar change when the user changes page?

Comment: Most websites that use this feature, don't actually navigate the browser away from the page, but instead display pages dynamically using Ajax in the same exact window. literally staying in the same page.

Comment: Could you use a shared web worker?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs yes, but I never used any, so maybe you could post an answer suggesting how to :)

Comment: To my mind the only way to do this is to pop out the new window when the user clicks 'select files' button. When done, you could try to use `postMessage` to the parent window to notify about upload state.

Comment: @SpadarShut please post your comment as an answer, it looks like I'll accept it...

Comment: So what was the final soluton in production?

Comment: @SpadarShut Well It's not in production yet, still alpha, but I chose to pop up an upload window, letting the users navigate the site while uploading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since navigating the site will switch pages and it's unlikely that there's a full ajax navigation on your site, maybe it could help to somehow upload the files in a second popup window. Not sure how (if) it could be implemented, though, but since you need to upload multiple files at a time I'm afraid you're bound to use flash.

**EDIT**

So the solution could look like this:

When a user clicks a "select files" button you pop out a new window where he'll be able to actually select files (via flash if multifile upload is necessary). And to notify of upload progress use `postMessage`. Though [postMessage isn't going to work in IE](http://caniuse.com/x-doc-messaging) in this case, but probably you could somehow send the message to the server and from the server back to the page.

Another crazy idea is not to use a popup window, but let the user select the files on the page she was first, but once the user selects the files make all the links on the page `target=_blank` to make any subsequent navigation happen in another tab. I know it's hacky and not exactly user-friendly, but probably could help.

In any case I would inform the user beforehand that a new window will appear in both scenarios.

**EDIT2**

And an even crazier idea. When the user selects the files and clicks a link create an iframe which will cover the whole page and hide the original page beneath it and make the links open in the iframe. But it looks even more hackish and it seems you'll have much trouble with it.

Comment: +1, a popup window i think will do the trick, because is considered another page which is not reloaded, any ajax/flash/etc could run there.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to pass the user selected files to the popup window unless the user selects the files in it.

Comment: First of all: crazy ideas are not evil. Many everyday things are born from crazy ideas. 
The first crazy idea is viable, I think I'll give it a try just to see how it works. The second has 2 big problems: the URL bar will keep showing the URL of the old page and never update, and if someone repeats the upload-click more than once, the client browser would use a lot of RAM and in the end slow down navigation

Comment: Just thought that to inform IE users of upload progress you could just change page title.

Comment: I like 'Another crazy idea' in the first edit. manipulating attributes on DOM elements to open a new window/tab isn't hacky in my opinion. Maybe alter the title to say that the files are uploading so that the user knows something is going on. And then when upload is complete, bring that window back into focus. :).