# Upload file with XHR/Ajax while user changes pages

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am currently working in a webpage that its main function is based in video uploads, and as these files could be very heavy, it would be interesting to continue the upload even if the user changes the page. Is that possible?

For now, I use asynchronous XMLHttpRequests for doing so, but it doesn't work if you move to other pages even in the same site:

```
xhr.open("POST", "{% url 'X' %}", true);
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: If you use AJAX for loading pages that wouldn't be a problem

Comment: This might be a possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519449/upload-multiple-files-while-navigating-other-pages-howto